# Alter breadcrumb for the taxonomy term edit page

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

To ease the navigation in the administration theme I would like the breadcrumb of /taxonomy/term/ID/edit

**To be** :
Home | Administration | Structure | Taxonomy | TaxonomyName | TermName | Edit

**Rather than** :
Home | ID | Edit

The ID currently leads to front end view page, and there is NO way on the page to detect of WHICH taxonomy this term is part of. Can you help where I should hook?
Thanks!

Comment: try https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb for a quick win if not you will need to 
see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter/8.2.x
and good luck ha ha I have a comment on there called "DEAR loard I am now Blind"

Comment: Another approach would be to change the term edit page to an admin path.

Comment: @4k4, Can you specify what you mean by "change the term edit page to an admin path"?

Comment: @taggartJ, Indeed, I will first dig into Easy Breadcrumb, hoping I can pull the term parent TaxonomyName, and make it work only on administration.

Comment: @MastaP, this would be the cleanest solution. When you create a custom entity you normally make the design decision whether to have the entity forms in the admin or non-admin path and this reflects in breadcrumbs built by core. For content core decided to make it configurable to use admin or standard themes and thus the path is not within the admin path to make it accessible in both cases.

Comment: @4k4, sorry I am not sure I understand how to implement this. Can you include some pointers in Drupal doc or any article to guide? Was it clear that all I want is to alter the breadcrumb in the ADMIN side for terms edit page?